# Best way to render a sortable table from a Django Model which displays custom fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I want to generate a table based on selected fields from a model(decided by an algorithm), and I want to be able to sort the columns in that table. I also want the user to be able to click on a button on each row which leads to a new page generated by a key from that row (ie. "edit")

I have tried django-tables2, but it seems that this would prevent me from adding the buttons and adding the algorithms I want which govern what types of fields are on display.

The generation of the custom table itself is not a problem - but I can't seem to find any sources on making a sorting function. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the perfect solution through sortables, which has Django use explained in [this article](https://djangoandy.com/2021/07/10/making-html-tables-sortable-without-backend-shenanigans/).

Although sortables does not give you the advanced functions of Datables, it is very easy to implement, and allows you to keep all of your back-end logic in one view. This allows for ease of implementation if you have a table populated by data depending on action from your user, where alternatives like Datatables and Django Tables require you to add functionality to your table in order to allow it to handle request data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use django-datatables (https://github.com/shymonk/django-datatable) that supports sort functionality by default. Is based on datatables (https://datatables.net/)